# how can i include my php code in Html template.?

Tags: php, html

I have my previous php .now i want to use it in my new html template which is recently made . i use all php at the top of the html before. but in my new html it is not working correctly why. please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use PHP syntax inside of HTML anywhere. Make sure HTML code has extension FileName.php in which you want to use PHP code.

```
<?php
   //Let me use some of the varaibles to use in HTML
   $title = "Title of page";
   $td1 = "TD1";
   $td2 = "TD2";
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         <!-- Below is the syntex to use php variable -->
         <?php echo $title; ?>
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <?php echo $td1;  ?>
            </td>
            <td>
               <?php echo $td2; ?>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

[Click here to test for this code to generate HTML from PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f386d9a74a367807345774b551531845e24c4b6f)

[Output will be like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKyDk.png)

I hope you'll got it how it works. Let me know if face any confusion.

Thank you.

Comment: thanks. I want background image by using php .how can i get image for background  my img url in css. what is the best way.?

Comment: Can you please paste your code here so that I assist you accurately. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could post some code and state your desired effect, but what I understand is that you want to include PHP code in you HTML document. That is pretty simple. You just include the PHP tags in the HTML file, and they will be rendered before it reaches the client.

Here is an example:

```
<h1><?php echo "Hello World!" ?></h1>
```

is equivalent to

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Note that if you want **dynamic** results, meaning that data is retrieved from the PHP file *after* the page loads, you will need to use AJAX and HTTP requests.